# how to show multiple tooltip on google stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i'm new to google chart.

i need to show multiple tooltips on google stacked chart.

i'm used this stacked bar chart chart :- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

i have a problem show only one value:- [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx1DB.png)

i need to show tooltip like :- [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtFOZ.png)

Comment: Try To Add focusTarget: 'category',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `focusTarget`

```
    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        focusTarget: 'category', // try to add
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true
      };
```

Please Check For More:- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content